# Powershell script to list folders in all shares

Tags: powershell

Stupid question but not sure if this is possible.

I have a file server hosting 8 separate shares. I was looking for a script to pull a list of the folder names (No subfolders) for all of the shares.

I can use **Get-ChildItem -path "\server1\share1*" | Where {$_.PsIsContainer}** to list the folders of a specific share but I'm trying to find a way to just use the server path to list all shares and folders at once.

Is the only option to run the script individually for each share?

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT Name, Path FROM Win32_Share" | Format-Table Name, Path
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the -recurse parameter for Get-Childitem, this lists the contents of each folder beneath (and their contents too), though if there are many folders this might become unwieldy.

Another option is to use wildcards (*).

```
Get-Childitem -path "\server1\*\*"
```

This will search any folders in "\server1" and then any folders in those folders, if you want it to  go deeper (dir-ception!) you can just add more "*".